# How to insert theta symbol in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, big-o

I want to write the time complexities as comments for my algorithms but how do I insert theta?

Comment: Assuming the source encoding already is UTF-8 (a setting) you can copy the character for instance from the Character Map accessory.

Comment: Just copy the symbol from anywhere on the [internet](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+03B8) and paste it into editor.

Comment: I use Alt+952 on OneNote and MS-Word. Just wanted to know if there's anything like that when it come to IntelliJ.